# Trying to get values in list of tuples format, got theTypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with 4 columns:

```
user_id item_id ratings timestamp
1   292     5   838983421
1   356     5   838983653
1   588     5   838983339
3   1408    3   1133571145
3   3408    4   1164885590
3   6539    5   1133571238
4   21      3   844416980
```

I need the values of "item_id" and "ratings" of a particular user in the format of a list of tuples, for example for user 1:

```
[(292, 5), (356, 5), (588, 5)]
```

likewise for user 3 and 4. So I use "zip" for this task. Below is the sample code. Note the use of the parameter `df`; `df` is a [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) (from the [**pandas**](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library).

```
def get_value(df, index, column1, column2):
    if index in df.index:
        values = list(zip(df.loc[index][column1], df.loc[index][column2]))
    else:
        values = []
    if type(values) is int:
        values = [values]
    return values

for u_id in ts_users:
    match_id = get_value(ui_training, u_id, 'item_id', 'ratings')
    print(match_id)
```

The code is working fine when there are more than 1 entry for each user. But if there is only single entry for a user, for example in the above data I have a single entry for user 4, then the code throws an error

```
values = list(zip(df.loc[index][column1], df.loc[index][column2]))
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

How could I get rid of this error?

Comment: Could you please show the output if you print `df.loc[index][column1]`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 user_id
    1    292
    1    356
    1    588

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using pandas (as it appears you are), there is no need to use zip for this.

Instead, use the functionality built into data frames, like so:

```
import pandas as pd


def get_value(df, uid, column1, column2):
        values = df.ix[df['user_id'] == uid][[column1, column2]].values
        return [tuple(elem) for elem in values]

# load data -> I'm assuming your separator is whitespace.
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=r"\s*")

# get values
values = get_value(df, 1, 'item_id', 'ratings')

print(values)
```

Output:

```
[(292, 5), (356, 5), (588, 5)]
```